# Seeing ConcurrentModificationException in Mule 3.3.0

Tags: mule

I am fairly new to Mule ,using 3.3.0, but I am trying what I think should be a fairly stock example.
I have a mule config which will read a csv file and attempt to process the lines and columns of in different flows async. However, we are seeing ConcurrentModificationException when the message is being "handed off" to one of the async flows. I was wondering if anyone else has seen this issue and what they may have done to work around the problem.

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>       at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(AbstractHashedMap.java:1113)
>       at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap$KeySetIterator.next(AbstractHashedMap.java:938)
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.setMessage(DefaultMuleEvent.java:933)
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.(DefaultMuleEvent.java:318)
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.(DefaultMuleEvent.java:290)
>       at org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent.copy(DefaultMuleEvent.java:948)

```
 <queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy poolExhaustedAction="RUN" name="commonProcessingStrategy" maxQueueSize="1000" doc:name="Queued Asynchronous Processing Strategy"/>

<file:connector name="inboundFileConnector" fileAge="1000" autoDelete="true" pollingFrequency="1000" workDirectory="C:/mule/orca/dataprovider/work"/>

<file:endpoint name="dataProviderInbound" path="C:\mule\orca\dataprovider\inbound" moveToPattern="#[function:datestamp]-#[header:originalFilename]" moveToDirectory="C:\mule\orca\dataprovider\history" connector-ref="inboundFileConnector" doc:name="Data Feed File" doc:description="new files are processed in 'work' folder, then moved to 'archive' folder"/>

<flow name="dataProviderFeedFlow">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="dataProviderInbound"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer />
    <flow-ref name="dataSub"/>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="dataSub" >

    <splitter expression="#[rows=org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(message.payload, '\n\r')]" />
    <expression-transformer expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(message.payload, ',')]" />
    <foreach>

        <flow-ref name="storageFlow" />
        <flow-ref name="id" />            

     </foreach>

</sub-flow>

<flow name="storageFlow" processingStrategy="commonProcessingStrategy">
    <logger level="INFO" message="calling the 'storageFlow' sub flow."/>
</flow>

<flow name="id" processingStrategy="commonProcessingStrategy">
    <logger level="INFO" message="calling the 'id' sub flow."/>
</flow>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your configuration. Why not using a second expression splitter after the first? Not sure what the `foreach` is used for? Also there's no `all` around the `storageFlow` and `id` flow-refs so this means you want the result of `storageFlow` to be passed to `id`? But these private flows have an asynchronous processing strategy so they may not return any result. I'm confused :$

Comment: My inexperience is probably what is causing your confusion. The intent is to create a message that can then be passed to each of the flows when I tried a splitter and a all around the flow-refs I get an error :

Comment: No, I'm just trying to see if you went through other approaches/attempts before reaching that point. Anyways, can you share a simple input file so we can try to reproduce? Also please specify the expected behavior for the invocation of `storageFlow` and `id`: should they both receive the same message or be chained one after the other?

Comment: The expected behavior is that they should both receive the same message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of the `dataSub` sub-flow that works fine:

```
<sub-flow name="dataSub">
    <splitter expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(message.payload, '\n\r')]" />
    <splitter expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.split(message.payload, ',')]" />
    <flow-ref name="storageFlow" />
    <all>
        <async>
            <flow-ref name="storageFlow" />
        </async>
        <async>
            <flow-ref name="id" />
        </async>
    </all>
</sub-flow>
```

Notice that:

- I use two splitter expressions,
- I use an `all` message processor to ensure the same payload is sent to both private flows,
- I have to wrap the flow-refs with an `async` message processor otherwise the invocation fails because the private flows are asynchronous but `all` forces synchronous.

Comment: Great and thanks! Do you know why or could you venture a guess as to why the exception was happening? Conceptually it seemed ok to me ... so I would like to know what was going on to adjust my understanding.

Comment: In not 100% sure but I imagine that because `foreach` alters the message properties (it sets flow variables) and because the messages are processed asynchronously and serialized due to your usage of `queued-asynchronous-processing-strategy`, messages where being expected to be in steady state when they were not. In general, avoid `foreach` unless you have a strong case for using it. Finally, if my solution works for you, please accept it.